# Get IP address by subnet in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a couple machines, each with multiple network interfaces:

```
lead$ ip addr
2: enp0s2: ...
    inet 10.1.1.11/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global enp0s2
3: enp0s3: ...
    inet 10.2.2.11/24 brd 10.2.2.255 scope global enp0s3

iron$ ip addr
2: enp0s99: ...
    inet 10.1.1.12/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global enp0s99
3: enp0s3: ...
    inet 10.2.2.12/24 brd 10.2.2.255 scope global enp0s3
```

Note that on `lead`, `10.1.1.0/24` is on `enp0s2`, but on
`iron`, `10.1.1.0/24` is on `enp0s99`.

In Puppet, how would I get the IP address(es) (or interface name)
corresponding to the subnet `10.1.1.0/24`? Using `$::ipaddress_enp0s2`
clearly won't work, as the interface name is different across machines.
What I want is something like `$::ipaddress_10_1_1_0` (with the value
`10.1.1.11` on `lead` and the value `10.1.1.12` on `iron`).

For reference: In Ansible, I would do something like:

```
- shell: "ip route get 10.1.1.0 | awk '{print $6}'"
  register: ipaddr
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ipaddr.stdout }} is my IP on 10.1.1.0/24"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the same approach in Puppet, using [custom facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) to create your own.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet Labs actually has an implementation of exactly this [in their puppetlabs-openstack module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-openstack/blob/17e8ed69150368e69492aa1362500fdffd497617/lib/puppet/parser/functions/ip_for_network.rb):

```
require "ipaddr"

module Puppet::Parser::Functions

  newfunction(:ip_for_network, :type => :rvalue, :doc => <<-EOS
Returns an ip address for the given network in cidr notation

ip_for_network("127.0.0.0/24") => 127.0.0.1
    EOS
  ) do |args| 
    addresses_in_range = [] 

    range = IPAddr.new(args[0])
    facts = compiler.node.facts.values
    ip_addresses = facts.select { |key, value| key.match /^ipaddress/ }

    ip_addresses.each do |pair|
      key = pair[0]
      string_address = pair[1]
      ip_address = IPAddr.new(string_address)
      if range.include?(ip_address)
        addresses_in_range.push(string_address)
      end
    end

    return addresses_in_range.first
  end
end
```

Rather than making a custom fact, this loops over the existing facts and finds ones that look like IP addresses.